# Local Currency Payment verification fails using curl php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, payment

I am implementing Facebook's new local currency payments to a canvas app and everything works fine except verifying the payments with a server side Facebook Graph call using PHP curl.

I keep getting the following message:

```
"error":{
    "message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":2
}
```

The php code:

```
$url  = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$payment_id.'/?access_token='.$access_token;
$data = get_url($url);

function get_url($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    $tmp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $tmp;
}
```

The graph link alone works fine when pasting it in a browser so the payment_id and access_token are correct, but it's not working with php curl.

Other graph calls work fine using the same curl function though.

Has anyone here successfully implemented the local currency payment with server verification?

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What call is your code actually making out to Facebook's servers? Are you sure your code is requesting the same URL the Facebook SDK would? Are the access token and payment ID both being passed correctly?

Comment: I am reading the payment information as described in Step 5a: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/canvas-games/payments/#step5a and I have checked that the same access token and payment ID work when pasting the full graph link in a browser.

Comment: Have you tried the same url in the browser with your FB session close? Because for me the url works only when FB has a session open, if you close the session the url only works sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to get a return id on a payment id with he following code:

> Note: test purchases will not return from api request. "i need to
>   verify this in docs".

*errors for bug: even with full access to app with access token, only the id is returning and the api is restricting the rest of the info, in my case.*

---

```
<?php
function GetCH($url){
$ch=null;
if(!$ch){
$ch = curl_init();
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "".$url."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$return=curl_exec($ch);
 if(!curl_errno($ch)){
return $return;
 }else{
$fb_fail=curl_error($ch);
return $fb_fail;
}
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);
};
$payment_id = '901177xxxxxxxxxxx?fields=id,amount,application,created_time,from,status,updated_time,items';  // notice the request for more than just the id using expansion.
$access_token = '135669679827333|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // app access token.
$url  = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$payment_id.'&access_token='.$access_token;
$returned=GetCH($url);
$locs=json_decode($returned, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($locs);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

---

**Place Holder for ref to bug report.**

Comment: Thanks Shawn. When adding my payment_id and token I get the following exception: `(#100) Unknown fields: amount,from,status,updated_time` Removing these fields and using all or some of these `fields=id,application,actions,refundable_amount,items,country,created_time,fraud_status,payout_foreign_exchange_rate,test` the full graph link works fine in the browser showing the correct result, but the result from your code and my id and token is still `An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.`. I am using a test payment's payment_id. Do you think that can be an issue?

Comment: I went into my profile, and got the id from a receipt of my own.

Comment: Did you try using the cURL function i posted?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and just changed the payment_id and app token. All graph calls except reading the new Local Currency payment information work fine so it seems to have something to do with that.

Comment: Shawn: The receipt you tried that worked, was that a payment_id created from the new local currency payment system? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/payments/ Also did you use the apps own access_token? I am trying to narrow down why this isn't working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No it was from the old system, you will need to post a bug and add this link for referrence.

Comment: Sorry i am mobile with my babies or i would start the bug report for you.

Comment: The code worked when we ran it from another server, but we have not been able to find why it is not working on our own system. All other Facebook Graph calls work except checking Local Currency Payments. Do you know of any settings that could cause this? Thanks.

Comment: If the callback url is not available or "possibly" if it does not match the domain settings.  I have not tested the same domain yet, i should be able to today at some point.  It is not documented yet whether the domains need to match.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It's not about how you send the cUrl request to the graph.
It's because the API doesn't respond accordingly when you don't have a facebook session.

That's why the same link doesn't work in cURL but works in a browser (with an active facebook session).

Now, there could be a solution to do this but i wouldn't rely on that.
1) Login through cUrl to a facebook account and save the session in a file. 
2) Use that file to have the session and therefore make the needed cURL request.

So, i'm also kinda' stuck. Anyone found a better sollution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the bug reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/283875851753617

Here's the code for whoever is going to get stuck on this crazyness.

(NOTE: not reliable because randomly it doesn't return what it should, instead is returning An "unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.")

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $payment_id . '?access_token=YES_APP_TOKEN_TOKEN');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'c_user=APP_ID');  //not reliable, because not always working.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```